# Contact Unsubscribed - where do they go?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, unsubscriber

I was told by our SFMC rep that once a contact visits our profile center page and unsubscribes that I won't be able to message them anymore (which is a good thing).

However, I'm wondering if this is universal through the MC suite.  For example: I have a journey that had 40 contacts unsubscribe.  I had to make a copy of that journey and restart it.  Used the same audience.  I assumed that the system would automatically reject those contacts that unsubscribed.  Is that true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a contact unsusbcribes, they have their status on the AllSubscriber's List changed to Unsubscribe, so any messages sent to them will be held. In your case, even though you are using the same audience, they will not get any message as the system will check against the AllSubscriber's List.

Also as [Markus Slabina](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/36218/markus-slabina) has pointed out, this only holds Emails sent using the "Commercial Send Definition". Contacts will still continue to receive transaction emails (i.e receipts, password reminders etc).

There is also a slight nuance between a global unsubscribe (where a contact unsubscribes from all communications, registered in the All Subscribers) and a list unsubscribe (where a contact unsubscribes from a particular publication list)

Also as [Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) points out, If your preference center is logging an unsub event and the send is associated with a List or Publication, then the unsubscribe is isolated to that list membership. Also unsubscribes are localized to the business unit if designated in the BU configuration

For more information please visit: [**Unsubscribes**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/unsubscribes/)

Comment: Building reputation...won't let me accept for another 4 min.  I got you!

Comment: Another important piece of information: The unsubsribe status only applies to commercial emails, so the contact will receive all messages sent using a transactional send definition. (Also described in the [documentation about unsubscribes](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/unsubscribes/))

Comment: very true will update answer

Comment: If your preference center is logging an unsub event and the send is associated with a List or Publication, then the unsubscribe is isolated to that list membership.  Also unsubscribes are localized to the business unit if designated in the BU configuration.